# Enumerating hardware info using their hardware Id from ASP.Net app

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, wmi

I want to know, can I enumerate all hardwares or unknown hardwares using a web application in .Net / WMI etc. With windows application i am able to enumerate the hardwares but with ASP.Net application, i haven't experienced.

I know its a task of Full Trust, but i just want to know, for curiosity. If its possible. since nothing is impossible with technology, within technological limits... I think there might exists some framework for the same.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Environment:
VS2010
C# 4.0
ASP.Net
WMI/framework you suggest...

**In Short:**

**I am talking about enumerating hardwares in Windows Device Manager. Basically i am thinking to enumerate unknown h/w from device manager and search for its driver on the web, via an automated process.**

Comment: You want to write an ASP.Net application to emulate arbitrary hardware?  You mean, like an Amiga emulator?

Comment: ??? I have no idea about Amiga. I am talking about enumerating Windows Device Manager. Basically i am thinking to enumerate unknown h/w from device manager and search for its driver on the web, an automated process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not enumerate hardware (or even access local files) from browser (assuming you want to use ASP.Net to render pages).

So you only option is to create a tool that user will install locally and run with enough privilegies.